# Vertically aligning multiple timeseries plots

Tags: plot, clojure, time-series, incanter

I've got measurements of several different quantities made during the same range of time. How can I plot them all in the same window, so they're all vertically aligned—that is, so that for any given time *t,* all the data points for that time have the same *x* (horizontal) coordinate in the window?

The timeseries should not all be on the same plot: each should be on a separate graph, with each graph very short in height, something like this:

[image: Rough pen sketch]

Comment: I think you may need to place each chart into a JFreeChart `ChartPanel` and then stack them inside another Swing panel:  http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html

Comment: @AlanThompson That could be a winner. Is there some way to do that in Incanter? Would I need to go to seesaw or to direct Java interop? (Sorry the first version of my question wasn't clear, by the way.)

Comment: Hmm, JFreeChart's [CombinedDomainXYPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html) might be able to do it.